# Bunch of matrices with vanishing permanents

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra, permanent

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Per}{Per}$
$\newcommand{\oI}{{\overline I}}$
$\newcommand{\oJ}{{\overline J}}$

> Is it possible to classify pairs $(A,B)$ of square, nonsingular matrices over a field of prime order $p\ge 5$, such that $\Per(AL+BM)=0$ for any diagonal matrices $L$ and $M$?

*Remark 1.* Notice that the assumption is that $A$ and $B$ are nonsingular, not that their permanents are nonzero.

*Remark 2.* A usable necessary condition is preferable over a formally correct, but unusable necessary and sufficient condition.

*Remark 3.* A necessary and sufficient condition is that for any proper, nonempty subset $J\subset[n]$ we have
$$ \sum_{|I|=|J|} \Per(A[I\times J]) \Per(B[\oI\times\oJ]) = 0, $$
where $\oI$ and $\oJ$ are the complements of $I$ and $J$, respectively, in $[n]$, the summation is over all subsets $I\subset[n]$ with $|I|=|J|$, by $A[I\times J]$ we denote the restriction of $A$ onto the rows indexed by the elements of $I$, and columns indexed by the elements of $J$, and similarly for $B[\oI\times\oJ]$. This, however, does not count as a comprehensible and useful classification.

*Remark 4.* I am aware of the papers of Akbari-Jamaali-Fakhari and Solymosi.